# Maximum number of console allowed in Pycharm python

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, pycharm, multiprocessing

I am relatively new to python and Pycharm.

Is there a limit to the maximum number of Python consoles I can open in Pycharm in a project?

I am trying to analyze 20 dataframes each of which would take about 3 hours. Hence 60 hours If I do serially. Alternate way would be to open multiple consoles and work in them. But is there a limit to number of consoles I can open?

Also, please correct me If I am wrong, but working with multiple consoles is the same is multiprocessing right?

Comment: multiprocessing means multiple processes running at the same time, so the direct translate into any other (literal) language would be yes, that's correct. But in the software world it generally means that one application can run multiple work-loads under the same application simultaniously. Opening one console with one instance of your software I would argue is not actual multiprocessing. Also, the limit is your RAM, nothing to do with Pycharm, Python or terminals. They'll just use resources like any other application (At least that I'm aware of).

Comment: Also, why not just try? If it works it works, right? Don't see the point in asking these questions as you already seam to have a computer with Python installed. Unless you're modifying the data - it should be safe to just try it out :) But just to be sure, **always** backup your data before you touch anything.